# Why is Valgrind complaining about printf instead of my uninitialized counter?

Tags: c, initialization, valgrind

I just started using Valgrind, and I'm not sure the error messages I get are what they should be. For instance, Valgrind just gave me a very long chain of warnings about `printf()` making jumps based on uninitialized memory. It was obviously that the issue wasn't with `printf()`. Rather, my program was giving `printf()` tainted memory.

I managed to produce the following MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int d;
    d++;
    printf("%d\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

It's really obvious that the problem here lies in `d++`. However, Valgrind only detects and warns me of uninitialized memory usage in the next line, with 6 messages in the form

> ==12178== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>   ==12178==    at 0x4E7F79D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1636)
>   ==12178==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
>   ==12178==    by 0x1086D1: main (mcve.c:7)

I compiled this with

> gcc mcve.c -g -O0

And I ran Valgrind with

> valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out

Then I discovered there's `--track-origins=yes`. It attempts to help, but it gets lost easily with pointers. For instance, it doesn't work for the next MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f2(int *p)
{
    (*p)++;
    return *p;
}

int f1(void)
{
    int d;
    return f2(&d);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", f1());
    return 0;
}
```

Here it says that the error is in the stack frame of `f1()`. It's kind of helpful, but considering the performance penalty involved, maybe it's not worth it.

What can I do to make best use of Valgrind?

Comment: As per the `c` guidelines to SO, shouldn't you be compiling with `-Wall` at minimum? I wouldn't call `valgrind` until I can at least get the compiler past it's minimum flag.  P.S. that is my answer to your question.

Comment: Why do you need Valgrind to tell you what the compiler can, before you even run it?

Comment: Because Valgrind is (roughly) a runtime memory leak checker, not a static code-analyser.

Comment: @WeatherVane in a more complicated piece of code with the same error, the compiler might not tell you

Comment: @KevinDTimm, if you compile my second example with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpointer-arith`, GCC will issue no warnings. Neither will Clang with `-Weverything`. A static analyzer that doesn't assume its pointer arguments point to valid memory would probably be prohibitively complex.

Comment: @M.M and in the second example, it (MSVC) doesn't. But as Olaf wrote, is that Valgrind's job?

Comment: @WeatherVane that comment doesn't make much sense , there's no memory leak in OP's code.  The question is why valgrind apparently does perform its unintialized variable analysis on a function parameter, but does not perform the same analysis on an operand of `++`.  It seems reasonable to think valgrind's job would either include both of those or none.

Comment: @M.M are you on my case? As Olaf wrote, "Valgrind is ... not a static code-analyser". Perhaps Valgrind throws that in as an "extra".

Comment: @WeatherVane It did some analysis to produce the error message . Do you call that static analysis or not? Either way the question remains why it did not perform the exact same analysis on the previous line.

Comment: So what's Valgrind's job anyway? In my case, I want to make use of its memory debugger aspect. What's the best way to use Valgrind to help me find use of unitialized memory?

Comment: @M.M if you want to say something useful you will perhaps be keen to advise me how to log out from the recently updated SO site.

Comment: @WeatherVane There seems to be a "log out" link in the popup that appears when you click the right-most icon on the top bar  (the broken speech bubble)

Comment: @M.M thank you. The right-click gives a standard browser context menu, left-click has the log-out.

Comment: Without `printf("%d\n", d);`, `d++;` can be optimized away.  So `d++` may not be a worthy issue.  Try using `d`, after the `d++` UB in another way and see it the system complains.

Comment: About track origin : this tells where the uninitialised value comes from (which is f1 stack frame). This option does not tell where your bug is. So, valgrind track origin is not lost with your pointer example, it properly reports the origin of the uninitialised data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deliberate decision in Valgrind is that it does *not* complain
just because some uninitialised memory is copied or similar.
It complaints only when the use of uninitialised memory changes the
*behaviour* of your program. This deliberate choice avoids a lot of false-positive errors.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.uninitvals
for more information.